# Storing Ruby in a YAML file

Tags: ruby

I've got an idea, but it's implications scare me. Perhaps you, dear reader, can help. :)

**The Setup**

I've created a Ruby-based CLI app that allows user configuration via a YAML file. In that file, there is scenario where the user can define pre and post "actions" that display a message (with some arbitrary, non-relevant code in-between). For example:

```
actions:
  - action
      # ...other keys...
      pre:
        message: 'This is the pre message'
        action: puts 'PRE COMMAND'
      post:
        message: 'This is the post message'
        action: puts 'POST COMMAND'
```

In this case, my app would output `This is the pre message`, evaluate the "pre" action (thus outputting `PRE COMMAND`), do some irrelevant stuff, output `This is the post message`, and finally evaluate the "post" action (thus outputting `POST COMMAND`).

**The Problem**

You can already guess the problem; it appeared when I used the word "evaluate". That's a scary thing. Even though this is a locally-run, client-centric app, the idea of eval'ing random Ruby is terrifying.

**Solution Idea #1**

The first idea was just that: eval the actions. I quickly destroyed it (unless one of you knows-more-Ruby-than-me types can convince me otherwise).

**Solution Idea #2**

Do some "checking" (via Regexp, perhaps) to validate that the command is somehow "valid". That seems wildly large and difficult to contain.

**Solution Idea #3**

Another idea was to wrap acceptable commands in data structures of my own (thus limiting the possibilities that a user could define). For instance, I might create an `open_url` action that safely validates and opens a URL in the default browser.

I like this idea, but it seems rather limiting; I'd have to define a zillion wrappers over time, it seems like. But perhaps that's the price you pay for safety?

**Your Turn**

I appreciate any additional thoughts you have!

Comment: But surely this is just a variant of the problem that _any_ user-customizable framework faces. When Ruby On Rails turns to me and lets me inject my own code into the page-rendering process, anything can happen. That's life; that's programming. I wouldn't advise `eval` of a string; it might be better if your "action" were a reference to a _script file_ that you can load (require) and call. But this sort of thing is a cooperative venture; if the user wants to shoot his/her foot off, you can't prevent it.

Comment: Correct, @matt. My intent in asking was to see what the brain trust viewed as an elegant way to address the problem (of which your comment is one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be a lot better off writing a simple framework that allows for Ruby plugins than to glue together something out of YAML and snippets of code.

You're right that "eval" is terrifying, and it should be, but sometimes it's the most elegant solution out of all possible inelegant solutions. I'd argue that this time is not one of those cases.

It's not at all hard to write a very simple DSL in Ruby where you can express your configuration in code:

```
action.pre.message = 'This is the pre message'
action.pre.command do
  puts "PRE COMMAND"
end
```

All this depends on is having a number of pre-defined structures that have methods like `message=` taking a string as an argument or `command` taking a block. If you want to get fancy you can write some `method_missing` handlers and make up things as you go along, allowing for maximum flexibility.

You can see many examples of this, from your `Rakefile` to [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), and it usually works out a lot better than having a non-Ruby configuration file format with Ruby in it.

Comment: Thank you, @tadman. Currently, my app translates several YAML keys that get translated into specific data structures/etc. in the app itself. I'm thinking that a combination of a DSL that maps to YAML keys. Might maintain flexibility while enforcing the security I desire.

(aka, I see what you're getting at ;) )